# ¿Por qué obtengo este error en Java?

Tags: java, mysql

No me deja agregar la venta en mi botón `btnGuardar6` me aparece este error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
```

Mi código:

```
private void btnGuardar6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { boolean verfiica = txtIdcliente.getText().isEmpty() || txtIdproducto.getText().isEmpty() || txtDescripcion.getText().isEmpty() || txtCantidad.getText().isEmpty() || txtPrecio.getText().isEmpty();

    if (verfiica) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Rellene todos los campos para realizar  la venta");
} else {

    conexionDB = new ConnectionDataBase();
    conexion = conexionDB.getConectionDB();

    int idCliente = Integer.parseInt(txtIdcliente.getText());
    int idProducto = Integer.parseInt(txtIdproducto.getText());
    String fecha = txtFecha.getText();
    String descripcion = txtDescripcion.getText();
    int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(txtCantidad.getText());
    double precioVenta = Double.parseDouble(txtPrecio.getText());

    String queryInsertVenta = "INSERT INTO ventas "
            + "VALUES(null, '" + idCliente + "','" + idProducto + "','" + fecha + "', '" + descripcion + "', '" + cantidad + "', '" + precioVenta + "')";

    try {

        sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
        sentencia.execute(queryInsertVenta);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha Guardado un nuevo registro");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("-->");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        conexionDB.closeConexion();
        closeRecursos();
    } finally {
        conexionDB.closeConexion();
        closeRecursos();
    }
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas sobre los `prepared Statement`, ayuda mucho para evitar errores de este tipo

Comment: Es muy importante ver la estructura de tu tabla ojala pudieras agregarla.

Comment: A la sentencia INSERT INTO ventas le falta que agregues los nombres de las columnas ejemplo:
INSERT INTO ventas(col1,col2,col2)values(value1,value2,value3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ## INSERT INTO Syntax
>
> Hay dos formas de escribir la sentencia INSRT INTO.
>
> En la primer forma especificas tanto las columnas como lo los valores a ser introducidos:
>
> ```sql
> INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
> VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
> ```
>
> Si estás agregando los valores de todas las columnas de la tabla, no necesitas especificar los nombres de las columnas en la consulta SQL. Asegúrate que el orden de los valores está en el mismo orden de las columnas en la tabla. La sintaxis INSERT INTO sería la siguiente:
>
> ```sql
> INSERT INTO table_name
> VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
> ```
>
> [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Verifica que el numero de columnas que estás introduciendo es el mismo que está en tu tabla.

Podría ser que tienes una columna `id` con un valor que no se está incrementando automáticamente.

El valor `null` en tu `VALUES` no se de que sea ya que no muestras como está tu tabla en la base de datos, pero al parecer es parametro no es lo que te está dando error

Answer (score 1):

> java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count

Ese es un error de MySql.

Verifica que las columnas que estás enviando coincidan con las de la Base de datos.

Según veo en tu código ingresas datos para 7 columnas en la tabla ventas. Verifica si son 7 columnas realmente en la base de datos.

Espero haber ayudado

Comment: gracias . el error estaba en una columna id con una valor que nos e incrementaba